# User authentication management with user token and session management in java web application

Tags: java, security, authentication, jakarta-ee

i am using  devise and authlogic in rails that provide all user management functionality with email sending , session management ,token  generation

is there any ready api available in java that provides all user login management functionality ?

please  suggests any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I got your question correctly..

For a user login functionality.. i assume u would need to accept user anme and password.. The UI part you will have to design.. the password encryption etc can be taken care of using MD5 or SHA or any other custom implementation. (u can refer to MessageDigest javadoc  or refer to a sample implementation here http://www.spiration.co.uk/post/1199/Java-md5-example-with-MessageDigest) Mailing.. can be taken care of using java mail or apache's mailing mechanism. you can look into http://commons.apache.org/email/ for details..Reg session management, there are several ways.. cookies  or maintaining session id's etc. if u are planning to generate session id's on your own.. u can use UUID api's given by java. you can refer to it. over here http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html .. Again.. I am sorry if this is not what you are looking for :)

Comment: thanks for your replay , but  i want ALL thing together in one package which give all functionality NOT want to do manually implementation